# Count of particular field from multiple tables in same server in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I have Asset table for 5 different zones. I would like to count Asset type from all table and display. When I use this query,

```
select AssetType,count(*) from MA.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
select AssetType,count(*) from VA.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
select AssetType,count(*) from RI.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
select AssetType,count(*) from NC.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
select AssetType,count(*) from VT.dbo.asset group by AssetType
```

It displays

```
Cash 1
Inventory 1
Cash 3
Patents 2
Goodwill 1
Patents 3
```

But I expect the output to be

```
Cash 4
Inventory 1
Patents 5
Goodwill 1
```

Can anyone help me in achieving this?

Comment: You could put another query around that and group again

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do was use that query as a *source* for your query, like this:

```
SELECT AssetType, SUM(Count) AS Count
FROM (
    select AssetType, count(*) as Count from MA.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
    select AssetType, count(*) as Count from VA.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
    select AssetType, count(*) as Count from RI.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
    select AssetType, count(*) as Count from NC.dbo.asset group by AssetType UNION ALL
    select AssetType, count(*) as Count from VT.dbo.asset group by AssetType 
) SubQ
GROUP BY AssetType
```

Note that subqueries require all their columns to have a name.